# Como repetir esse comandos em Python

Tags: python, loop

Gostaria de saber como eu faço um comando para o programa ficar repetindo esse código em uma determinada quantidade de vezes. Quero que ele repita de um em um minuto este código:

```
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("Ypffh").click()
    comment_input_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name("Ypffh")

    time.sleep(random.randint(2, 5))
    self.type_like_a_person(random.choice(comments), comment_input_box)

    time.sleep(random.randint(3, 5))
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Publicar')]").click()

    time.sleep(random.randint(3, 5))
    time.sleep(3)
```

Já tentei `while`, `for` e outros. Quero que ele fique fazendo um loop sempre nesses comandos acima.

Comment: Cara, a única forma de repetir esse código é com os laços de repetição `while` ou `for`. Qual exatamente foi o seu problema utilizando eles ?

Comment: Eu sei que é um bot. Mas a minha pergunta é o seu script vai apenas executar esse código repetidamente a cada minuto ou ele vai realizando outra atividade enquanto a cada minuto ele repete esse código?

Answer (score 2):

tudo certo. Eu já passei por uma situação semelhante a sua, porém não é exatamente igual.
O que eu poderia propor seria algo assim:

```
import time

init_time = time.time()

while True:
    end_time = time.time()

    if end_time - init_time < 60:
        driver.find_element_by_class_name("Ypffh").click()
        comment_input_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name("Ypffh")

        time.sleep(random.randint(2, 5))
        self.type_like_a_person(random.choice(comments), comment_input_box)

        time.sleep(random.randint(3, 5))
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Publicar')]").click()

        time.sleep(random.randint(3, 5))
        time.sleep(3)
```

Porém, devo avisar que o `time.sleep()` pode interferir nessa contagem. Além disso, isso vai travar o fluxo da sua aplicação, no caso o Python não é assíncrono, como Node.js.

Answer (score 1):

Boa noite, se a sua ideia é que ele se repita de tempo em tempo, eu acredito que melhor opção seja usar o scheduler, que é um bib python para agendar tarefas, ou uma forma que eu não acho muito interessante seria um while True e seu flag da parada poderia ser um contador, para quando ele se repetisse n vezes parasse. Mas acredito que ainda assim o melhor é o scheduler.

```
conte = 0

while True:

    """código aqui dentro"""
    conte += 1
    sleep(60) # repete o código a cada 60 segundos
    if conte == n:
        break
```

> n = número de vezes

Espero que tenha ajuda em algo.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar criar uma função para isso da seguinte forma:

> Apenas repassando: ***vezes*** representa o quanto de vezes que seu código vai rodar e ***intervalo*** o período de tempo entre cada execução.

```
def Repetir_meu_código(vezes, intervalo):

    for v in range(vezes):
        driver.find_element_by_class_name("Ypffh").click()
        comment_input_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name("Ypffh")

        time.sleep(random.randint(2, 5))
        self.type_like_a_person(random.choice(comments), comment_input_box)

        time.sleep(random.randint(3, 5))
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Publicar')]").click()

        time.sleep(intervalo)

Repetir_meu_código(10, 60) # Repetir 10 vezes a cada 60 segundos
```

Ou simplesmente usar o loop ***for*** fora da função bem assim:

> O ***v*** dentro do for representa quantas vezes o loop já rodou, sua contagem começa a partir do número ***0*** e vai até o valor definido em ***range()*** menos ***1***.
> Por exemplo se o ***range*** for ***10*** o último valor de ***v*** será ***9*** pois no python a contagem começa a partir do ***0***. O nome ***v*** pode ser trocado por qualquer outra coisa como ***i*** por exemplo ou ***qualquer outro nome***.

```
for v in range(10):
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("Ypffh").click()
    comment_input_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name("Ypffh")

    time.sleep(random.randint(2, 5))
    self.type_like_a_person(random.choice(comments), comment_input_box)

    time.sleep(random.randint(3, 5))
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Publicar')]").click()

    time.sleep(60)
```

> Fazendo este processo em modelo de ***função*** seu você tem mais controle sobre seu ***código*** e pode simplesmente ***chamar a função novamente para ser executada em outro momento*** ou até mesmo ***importar*** seu script para utilizar a função em outro código.

Deste modo você importa apenas a função escolhida:

```
from nome_do_script import função_escolhida
```

Importar todas:

```
from nome_do_script import *
```

Ou simplesmente importa todas também necessitando de especificação dentro do código:

```
import nome_do_script
```

> Aqui porém em todas as ***funções ou classes*** que você estiver importando precisar especificar para seu código atual a fonte da ***função ou classe***

```
nome_do_script_importado.função_importada()
```

> Note que não é preciso incluir as ***terminações*** ***(.py, .pyw e etc.)*** no import.